# "symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64" error due to C function

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c, xcode

I'm getting the following compile error in Xcode 8.1 with an iOS app project that uses a framework target which in turn makes use of a cocoapod that includes some C functions:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CUsingClass", referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref in libSDKFile.a(SessionManager.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've already exhausted all solution I found (build settings/architectures, etc.) and the C code even uses extern "C" directive (in C header file):

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #define CODE_EXPORT extern "C"
#else
    #define CODE_EXPORT extern
#endif

CODE_EXPORT unsigned int myCFunction(const char *src, char *dst, unsigned int dst_size);
```

The framework target that uses the cocoapod lib with the C file compiles successfully but the app target fails, giving the above error. App compiles successfully if i comment out the C function include.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: I think you're looking in wrong spot. The problem is not related to any C function. Instead, the class `CUsingClass` is missing entirely. This class most likely is written in Objective-C. Can you give us more information about this class? Is it part of the framework you have added via Cocoapod? What's its purpose? Is it the class that class the C functions?

Comment: @Codo yes, CUsingClass is an Objective-C class in a cocoapod that includes the C file (which is also in the same pod). There's nothing fancy in that class, other than that it calls a C function from the C file in one line.

Comment: I assume, the pod with `CUsingClass` class is your pod and not a third-party pod. Do you use another framework via a CocoaPod pod? If so, the problem is most likely with how your pod is configured. Otherwise, it's more likely witht the way you include the pod into your project.

Comment: @Codo The pod with CUsingClass is a thirdparty pod, not my own. The framework target that uses this pod is my own. compiling that Cocoa Touch framework target is successful.The Cocoa Touch framework target itself is referenced to the app target as a pod (via .podspec file).

Comment: Try all these things: Upgrade to the latest Cocoapods version. Clean build folder (option key and select Product / Clean Build Folder), close XCode and run `pod install` again. Check that `$(inherited)` was added to Build Settings -> Other linker flags -> double click. If the pod is delivered as a binary framework, check that it contains code for the simulator (x86_64) and not just for the devices (armv7, arm64).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Codo! After all it was an issue with the podspec file. Please see my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that the problem was that the dependency entry for the third-party pod wasn't set properly in the podspec file that is used to have my own framework target used as a pod for the app target. So adding the correct dependency entry and doing a pod install (and a clean) afterwards fixed this issue:

```
  s.dependency "ThirdpartyLib/Subspec"
```

I was missing the subspec.